# SQL Select Statement Not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select

This is what I have:

- A person *(unique ID)* generates a bill *(unique Bill ID)* .
- This is stored in `Store_Bill_Item_Details` table.

This is what I want to do:

- I run a SELECT in `Store_Bill_Item_Details` for all the `Bill_No` owned by the Person.
- Once I get a list of `Bill_No` from the above, I want it to recursively search in `Store_Bill_Details` to list all the items with their rates.

So my query result should look like this for an entered PersonID:

**Bill 1:**

**Details of bill1**

**Bill 2:**

**Details of bill2**

This is what I have that isn't working.

```
USE My_Database
Select I.Bill_No , ( SELECT * FROM Store_Bill AS I1
                   INNER JOIN 
                    Store_Bill_Details AS ID 
                    ON  
                    ID.Bill_No=II.Bill_No)  

    FROM Store_Bill_Item_Details AS BD 
    INNER JOIN 
    Store_Bill AS I 
    ON 
    BD.Item_Code=I.Bill_No
```

Please help me, guys!

Comment: What db platform? SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, sql-server. @paqogomez

Comment: What you are describing is a master-detail report.  There are several reporting softwares that can accomplish this, SSRS or Excel probably being the one most accessible.  It is simple to get all the data you need, but not display it the way that you require unless you use a reporting software.

Comment: Is it not possible using sql?

Comment: @divinediu You can't do `select *` in another `select` statement. `Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.`

Comment: use some reporting tools for this

Comment: 'Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.' I got this error. Not sure what that means. This is actually for billing. When I bill for a person, this is how data should be pulled.

Comment: @divinediu Means you are selecting multiple columns from the subquery (`SELECT * FROM Store_Bill`) which is not allowed. You can select a specified column from the `Store_Bill` table with proper conditions so that the subquery returns only one value per row or nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT * FROM Store_Bill AS I1 
 INNER JOIN Store_Bill_Details AS ID ON ID.Bill_No=I1.Bill_No
  INNER JOIN Store_Bill_Item_Details AS BD ON BD.Item_Code=I1.Bill_No
```

or try this

```
select * from 
   (select Person,bill,null as a,null as b....
   from Store_Bill_Item_Details
   union 
   select Null,bill,<field1>,<field2>,<field3>... 
   from Store_Bill_Details) aa
   order by bill,a
```

Comment: No, that won't work. I need it to work like a for each statement

Comment: @divinediu A cursor is not a bad idea, but you'd be printing out strings like a report.

Comment: Can you guide me with how I need to use a cursor for my data ? @paqogomez

Comment: insted or cursor you can use my alternate query..i guess it may meet your requirement...i forget to add alias to the columns in subquery....

Comment: Your second query will just list all the details, followed by all the bills.  not alternating as he wants them.